# print outnum to the standard output stream sample input 5,10,6,8 sample output 4

Tags: python

Consider an array of non-zero positive integers inarr. Identify and print a number outnum based on the below logic:

· Across each of the possible ways in which integers in inarr can be sequentially arranged, identify the maximum absolute difference of adjacent values

o The last and the first integers are adjacent

· Print outnum, the minimum value across the maximum differences identified above

Input:

The first line represents the array inarr with its elements separated by ‘,’(comma)

Read the inputs from the standard input stream

Output:

Print outnum to the standard output stream

Sample Input    Sample Output   Explanation

5,10,6,8    4

For the given inarr, the maximum absolute difference of adjacent values for all the possible ways in which integers can be arranged is as below:

5,10,6,8:

5 - 10 =5  àabsolute maximum difference

10 - 6 = 4

6 - 8 =2

8 - 5 =3

Similarly, for other possible ways:

5,10,8,6 - absolute max diff = 5

5,6,8,10 - absolute max diff = 5

5,6,10,8 - absolute max diff = 4

5,8,6,10 - absolute max diff = 5

5,8,10,6 - absolute max diff = 4

10,5,6,8 - absolute max diff = 5

10,5,8,6 - absolute max diff = 5

10,6,5,8 - absolute max diff = 4

10,6,8,5 - absolute max diff = 5

10,8,6,5 - absolute max diff = 5

10,8,5,6 - absolute max diff = 4

6,5,10,8 - absolute max diff = 5

6,5,8,10 - absolute max diff = 4

6,8,5,10 - absolute max diff = 5

6,8,10,5 - absolute max diff = 5

6,10,5,8 - absolute max diff = 5

6,10,8,5 - absolute max diff = 4

8,5,6,10 - absolute max diff = 4

8,5,10,6 - absolute max diff = 5

8,6,5,10 - absolute max diff = 5

8,6,10,5 - absolute max diff = 5

8,10,5,6 - absolute max diff = 5

8,10,6,5 - absolute max diff = 4

The minimum value across the maximum differences is 4

Answer (score 0):

This might be useful for you

```
def permutation(lst):
    if len(lst) == 0:
        return []
    if len(lst) == 1:
        return [lst]
    l = []
    for i in range(len(lst)):
       m = lst[i]
       remLst = lst[:i] + lst[i+1:]
       for p in permutation(remLst):
           l.append([m] + p)
    return l

data = [5,10,6,8]
got = []
for a in permutation(data):
    result = []
    for i in range(len(a)+1):
        if i > len(a)/2:
            result.append(abs(a[len(a)-1] - a[0]))
        else:
            result.append(abs(a[i] - a[i+1]))
    max_value = max(result)
    got.append(max_value)
print(list(set(sorted(got)))[0])
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

```
package com.company;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        BufferedReader bf = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        String [] str = bf.readLine().split(",");
        int arr[]  = new int[str.length+1];
        for (int i=0;i<str.length;i++){
            arr[i] = Integer.parseInt(str[i]);

        }
        for (int i=0;i< str.length;i++){
            int maxdif = 0;
            int diff =0;
            diff = arr[i] - arr[i+1];
            maxdif = diff;
            checkmax(Math.abs(diff));
            System.out.println(Math.abs(maxdif));


//      5,10,6,8

        }

    }
    public static int checkmax(int diff){
        int []num = new int[200];
        while (0<diff)
        System.out.println(num[]);
        return 0;

    }
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

```
int main()
{
    vector<int> vect = {5, 10, 6, 8};
    sort(vect.begin(), vect.end());

    int n = vect.size();
    int mid = n / 2;
    reverse(vect.begin() + mid, vect.end());

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        cout << vect[i] << " ";

    cout << endl;
    int maxx = INT_MIN;

    for (int i = 1; i < vect.size(); i++)
    {
        maxx = max(maxx, abs(vect[i] - vect[i - 1]));
    }

    cout << maxx << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

The following code should solve the problem.

`maxAbsDiff()` returns the maximum absolute difference of adjacent numbers for an array.

`minMaxAbsDiff()` iterates over all permutations of an array and returns the smallest maximum absolute difference.

```
import itertools

def maxAbsDiff(arr):
    max = 0
    for i in range(len(arr)-1):
        diff = abs(arr[i+1] - arr[i])
        if diff > max:
            max = diff
    diff = abs(arr[len(arr)-1] - arr[0])
    if diff > max:
        max = diff
    return max


def minMaxAbsDiff(arr):
    min = -1
    permutations = list(itertools.permutations(arr))
    for i in range(len(permutations)):
        diff = maxAbsDiff(permutations[i])
        if (min < 0) or (diff < min):
            min = diff
    return min




def input_intArr():
    str_in = input()
    str_arr = [x.strip() for x in str_in.split(",")]
    arr = []
    for i in range(len(str_arr)):
        arr.append(int(str_arr[i]))
    return arr



print(minMaxAbsDiff(input_intArr()))
```